# Does ordering matter in if-else statements for fizz buzz?

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I Just did the fizz buzz test, but I did it differently that the answer below. I put the first "if " statement (i.e., `i%3===0 && i%5===0`) as my last "else if" statement instead and for some reason it didn't work. My logic is the same however.

Does anyone know why it doesn't work? Does it really matter which position you put for the if, else statements? Below is the answer key.

```
for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++){
      if(i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0){
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
      }
      else if(i%3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
      }
      else if(i%5 === 0){
        console.log("Buzz");
      }
      else {
        console.log(i);
      }
}
```

This was my answer:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++){
     if (i%5 === 0){
        console.log("Buzz");
      }
      else if(i%3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
      }
      else if (i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0){
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
      }
      else {
        console.log(i);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put `if (i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0)` as the last `if` in the chain, then only *one* of the previous branches will be entered -- namely, `if (i%3 === 0)` or `if (i%5 === 0)`. Since you're using `else if`s, control will never enter the combined "FizzBuzz" `if`.

For example: let's say that `i = 15`. If you have the following code:

```
if(i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
}
else if(i%3 === 0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
}
else if(i%5 === 0) {
    console.log("Buzz");
}
else {
    console.log(i);
}
```

your output will be `FizzBuzz`. However, if you move the combined `if` to the end, like so:

```
if(i%3 === 0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
}
else if(i%5 === 0) {
    console.log("Buzz");
}
else if(i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
}
else {
    console.log(i);
}
```

then your output will be just `Fizz`, because `i%3 === 0`.

Comment: I don't think I get it. I don't see how having the fizz "if" statement and then the "buzz" if statement accounts for the if(i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0) b/c it's not getting BOTH (&&) of them...am I missing something??

Comment: @user3806909 I just realized that my answer was incorrect. I edited it.